# DB2 ODBC connection failed in SSIS after a while

Tags: ssis, db2, odbc

I am trying to load huge data (37 millions rows) from DB2 to flat file using ODBC connection via SSIS.
However, this is unstable. Sometimes, it failed, sometimes the job successfully completed. Each time it takes around 1 hour 10 mins to run on SSIS server.

Do you have any solutions to get rid of the following error?

> Error: Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) error occurred.  state:
>   '40003'. Native Error Code: -30081. [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30081N
>
> A communication error has been detected. Communication protocol: "TCP
>   / IP". Communications API: "SOCKETS". Address where the error was
>   detected: "57.57.49.160". Communication function where the error was
>   detected: "recv". Error codes for protocol: "10060", "*", "*".
>   SQLSTATE = 08001

Thanks in advance for you reply!

Comment: Maybe this will help you https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.cli.doc/doc/c0056198.html

Comment: A flatfile seems unlikely to be a final destination for 37 million rows. Perhaps you might give [some idea of your *real* goal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and we might be able to offer a better strategy for achieving that.